# Como realizar múltiplas inserções no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Sou iniciante e possuo um código em que preciso inserir múltiplos produtos dentro de uma lista de compras, porém, no código que fiz, só é possível inserir um JSON por vez.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("lista/addproduto")]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddProdutoNaLista(ProdutosLista prod)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ProdutosLista> lstProdLista = new List<ProdutosLista>();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRODLISTA VALUES (@codigo, @nome, @cbarra, @pco_remar, @unidade, @quantidade, @peso, @pco_total, @id_lista)";

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", prod.CodProduto);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", prod.Nome);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbarra", prod.CodBarra);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_remar", prod.Preco);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unidade", prod.Unidade);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", prod.Quantidade);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peso", prod.Peso);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_total", prod.PrecoTotal);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_lista", prod.IdLista);

                        lstProdLista.Add(prod);

                    if (prod.CodProduto != 0 && prod.Preco != 0 && prod.PrecoTotal != 0)
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstProdLista.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Caso eu passe apenas um JSON, insere normalmente, porém se eu passar mais de um JSON, retorna o seguinte erro no Postman:

> **"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."**

Imagino que seja por conta de eu estar atribuindo mais de um valor para as propriedades, pensei em colocar dentro de um while, mas não consigo pensar na condição do comando.

Comment: Para isso teria que receber como parâmetro uma lista de objetos do tipo `ProdutosLista`. Neste momento apenas está a passar uma instância do objeto, por isso só consegue inserir uma de cada vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entrarei em méritos de padrões da sua implementação. Olharei apenas o seu código.

Tu encaminhara a tua lista de itens por parâmetro usando JSON mesmo e automaticamente será feito o bind para a lista. Tendo a lista tu pode sim fazer as inserções em loop.

Acho que você está confundindo alguns pontos da sua implementação.

Vou ajustar o seu código como eu entendo que você deva trabalhar, pois não sei se entendi bem a sua dúvida.
Vamos lá:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("lista/addproduto")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddProdutoNaLista(List<ProdutosLista> lstProdLista )
```

Depois, dessa lista recebida você coloca um loop percorrendo a sua lista e ir adicionando os produtos.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("lista/addproduto")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddProdutoNaLista(List<Produto> lstProdLista )
{
    try
    {
        foreach(Produto item in lstProdLista){
            if (item.CodProduto != 0 && item.Preco != 0 && item.PrecoTotal != 0)
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRODLISTA VALUES (@codigo, @nome, @cbarra, @pco_remar, @unidade, @quantidade, @peso, @pco_total, @id_lista)";

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", item.CodProduto);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", item.Nome);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbarra", item.CodBarra);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_remar", item.Preco);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unidade", item.Unidade);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", item.Quantidade);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peso", item.Peso);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_total", item.PrecoTotal);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_lista", item.IdLista);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstProdLista.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

E tirando um pouco a verbosidade da para tirar um If e fazer assim o loop.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("lista/addproduto")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddProdutoNaLista(List<Produto> lstProdLista )
{
    try
    {
        foreach(Produto item in lstProdLista.Where(lp => lp.CodProduto != 0 && lp.Preco != 0 && item.PrecoTotal != 0)){
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PRODLISTA VALUES (@codigo, @nome, @cbarra, @pco_remar, @unidade, @quantidade, @peso, @pco_total, @id_lista)";

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo", item.CodProduto);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", item.Nome);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbarra", item.CodBarra);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_remar", item.Preco);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unidade", item.Unidade);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", item.Quantidade);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peso", item.Peso);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pco_total", item.PrecoTotal);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_lista", item.IdLista);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();  

                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstProdLista.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu estava buscando.